# jQuery call td with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that displays data retrieved from an API.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test="test";

    function display() {     
        $("#div1").append('<tr>
                           <th>A</th>
                           <th>B</th>
                           <th>C</th>
                           <th>D</th>
                           </tr>');

        $.post(url, {test:test}, function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                $("#div1").append('<tr><td>' + "Data 1" + '</td><td>' + 
                                               "Data 2" + '</td><td>' + 
                                               "Data 3" + '</td><td class="data4">' + 
                                               "Data 4" + '</td><td class="data5">' + 
                                               "Data 5" + '</td></tr>');
            }   
        });

        $("td:nth-child(3)").hide();
        $('td:nth-child(5)').live('mouseenter',function(){
            alert("Hello");         
        });
    }

    display();
});
```

The following line is not working:

```
$("td:nth-child(3)").hide();
```

However, the following code is working:

```
$('td:nth-child(5)').live('mouseenter',function(){
    alert("Hello");         
});
```

I have tried several ways such as:

```
$(".data4").hide();
$("td.data4").hide();
$("table tbody tr td.data4").hide();
```

But none is working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.7, the [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated in favour of [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#div1').find('td:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

Edit:
The part you want to hide is created by an asynchronous call so it's probably not yet created by the time you are trying to hide it.

Try hiding it within the callback scope, that way, it must have been created before the you try hiding it. That is after the `$('div1').append()`

**FURTHER EXPLANATION:**
$.post() is an asynchronous function which implies that the rest of the code continues to execute without waiting for it (the function call) to complete it's execution. That is why you couldn't hide that part because it hasn't been created at that time.
 Since you want to do something with the result, you'll need to wait for the function to finish execution.

The part of the code inside the $.post() function

```
$.post($url, data, function(data)  { 
    // this part will execute when the asynchronous function completes 
});
```

is called a callback function. That part executes after your asynchronous call completes, and by then the data you want to hide has been created.

Comment: there 2 appends sir, which one are you referring to?

Comment: oh yeah sir! it works, can you explain a bit more about how it works? If i put the codes like above sample, it is correct right? because i put it after the ajax call has done.

Comment: omg sir, this is really clear! You are very good in explaining! now I know! Thank so much!

Comment: But sir why is the $('td:nth-child(5)').live('mouseenter',function(){ alert("Hello"); }) still able to work eventhough i put it outside of the callback function? should be inside the callback function right?

Comment: @Foster Yes it should be inside the callback function.
.live() binds events to controls created on the fly, or later after the html document has been normally loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if you know table id or class then try this:

```
$('#tableID td:nth-child(3)').hide();// you can use it by table class also by removing # to .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `deferreds`, which will make sure your table is built completely before you try to hide one of its component, and it will provide a better structure for your code:

```
var getdata = function() { 
      var r = $.Deferred();

       $("#div1").append('<tr>
                   <th>A</th>
                   <th>B</th>
                   <th>C</th>
                   <th>D</th>
                   </tr>');
       $.post(url, {test:test}, function(data){
         for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                $("#div1").append('<tr><td>' + "Data 1" + '</td><td>' + 
                                               "Data 2" + '</td><td>' + 
                                               "Data 3" + '</td><td class="data4">' + 
                                               "Data 4" + '</td><td class="data5">' + 
                                               "Data 5" + '</td></tr>');
         }   
      }); 

      setTimeout(function () { r.resolve();}, 2500);

      // return the deferred object
      return r;
};

var display = function() { 
      $("td:nth-child(3)").hide();
      $('td:nth-child(5)').live('mouseenter',function(){
                alert("Hello");         
      }) 
};

getdata().done(display);
```

Comment: not working sir. i have added the when display function, but even it affects my live mouseenter function becomes not working

Comment: @Foster see my latest code above, you should use deferreds

Comment: the first line has problem sir, error it says. the var getdata() = function() {

Comment: @Foster I changed `var getdata()` to `var getdata` and this `var display()` to this `var display` please try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Since your are using ajax, it has to wait for the response. Move the code inside callback function.

```
$.post(url, {test:test}, function(data){
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

      $("#div1").append('<tr><td>' + "Data 1" + '</td><td>' + 
                         "Data 2" + '</td><td>' + 
                        "Data 3" + '</td><td class="data4">' + 
                        "Data 4" + '</td><td class="data5">' + 
                        "Data 5" + '</td></tr>');
    }  
    $("td:nth-child(3)").hide();
  });
```